Google login in React.js returning {error: 'popup_closed_by_user'}
`I tried to implement Google login using React.js, but I encountered an error. The error message is as follows:
{error: 'popup_closed_by_user'}
import React from 'react';
import { GoogleLogin } from 'react-google-login';

const clientId = "your-client-id";

function Login () {
    const onSuccess = (response) => {
        console.log("Login Success:", response);
    }

    const onFailure = (response) => {
        console.log("Login Failed:", response);
    }
  
    return(
        <div>
            <GoogleLogin 
                clientId={clientId}
                buttonText="Login with Google"
                onSuccess={onSuccess}
                onFailure={onFailure}
                cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
                isSignedIn={true}
            />
        </div>
    )
}



`
